# MuleSoft DataWeave to roll up joined query results

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have returned some data from a database call which joins several tables together. The current payload looks something like this:

```
[
 { "ID": 11111
 , "Ref": "123ABC"
 , "Year": 1994
 , "Title": "A title"
 , "Author": "Joe Bloggs"
 },
 { "ID": 11111
 , "Ref": "123ABC"
 , "Year": 1994
 , "Title": "A title"
 , "Author": "John Smith"
 },
 { "ID": 22222
 , "Ref": "456DEF"
 , "Year": 2018
 , "Title": "Another title"
 , "Author": "Lucy Jones"
 }
]
```

Can anyone help with the DataWeave required to translate it to this:

```
[
 { "ID": 11111
 , "Ref": "123ABC"
 , "Year": 1994
 , "Title": "A title"
 , "Authors": [ {"Name": "Joe Bloggs"}, {"Name": "John Smith"} ]
 },
 { "ID": 22222
 , "Ref": "456DEF"
 , "Year": 2018
 , "Title": "Another title"
 , "Authors": [ {"Name": "Lucy Jones"} ]
 }
]
```

I've tried playing around with distinctBy and filter, but have only managed to get this so far:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var myVar = payload distinctBy () -> 
   { ID: $.ID
   , Ref: $.Ref
   , Year: $.Year
   , Title: $.Title
   } 
---
myVar map () -> using (thisID = myVar.ID)
   { ID: $.ID
   , Ref: $.Ref
   , Year: $.Year
   , Title: $.Title
   , Authors: payload map {Name: $.Author} 
   //, Authors: payload filter ($.*ID contains thisID) map {Name: $.Author}
   }
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 11111,
    "Ref": "123ABC",
    "Year": 1994,
    "Title": "A title",
    "Authors": [
      {
        "Name": "Joe Bloggs"
      },
      {
        "Name": "John Smith"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Lucy Jones"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": 22222,
    "Ref": "456DEF",
    "Year": 2018,
    "Title": "Another title",
    "Authors": [
      {
        "Name": "Joe Bloggs"
      },
      {
        "Name": "John Smith"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Lucy Jones"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming fields other than the Author will be same for a particular ID, you can use [`groupBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-groupby) to make groups for each ID.
Then map the grouped values by updating the Author to be equal to the combined value of all the Author in the group.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy $.ID
    pluck ((groupedValues) -> {
        (groupedValues[0] - "Author"),
        Author: groupedValues map {Name: $.Author}
    })
```

Also note that `using` keyword is deprecated in Mule 4, so avoid using it. You should instead use the [`do` block](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dataweave-flow-control#control_flow_do) for it

Comment: That did the job, many thanks! I also found a neat trick on the MuleSoft forums where you can join the other values for use in the groupBy i.e. `groupBy ($.ID++$.Ref++$.Year++$.Title)`